# Relation between fan and toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

I understand what a fan is, but I don't really know how it associated to a toric variety. Could a non-toric variety has a fan?

Comment: Have you looked into one of the usual references on the subject? This is explained in essentially all of them!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Most of the usual sources do the fan -> toric variety direction, but most of them don't seem to fully cover the other direction.